# Python Text Searching in .txt files in different folders with printing the name of file and folder

Tags: python, file, path, directory, python-os

I'm making a script in Python for searching for the selected term (word/couple words, sentence) in a bunch of .txt files in a selected folder with printing out the names of the .txt files which contain the selected term. Currently is working pretty fine using `os` module:

```
import os

dirname = '/Users/User/Documents/test/reports'

search_terms = ['Pressure']
search_terms = [x.lower() for x in search_terms]

for f in os.listdir(dirname):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname,f), "r", encoding="latin-1") as infile:
        text =  infile.read()

    if all(term in text for term in search_terms):
        print (f)
```

But I wanna make the extension for the script: to be able to search not only in one folder (dirname), but in two for example (dirname1, dirname2) which consist of also .txt files. Also I would like to print not only the name of the searched report but the name of the directory (dirname) where it locates. Is it possible to do that using `os` module or there will be some other approaches to do that?

Comment: Put them in same directory and do an `os.walk()`

Comment: The method `walk()` generates the file names in a directory tree only by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over dirnames like this :

```
import os

dirnames = ['/Users/User/Documents/test/reports','/Users/User/Documents/test/reports2']

search_terms = ['Pressure']
search_terms = [x.lower() for x in search_terms]
for dir_name in dirnames:
    for f in os.listdir(dir_name):
        with open(os.path.join(dir_name, f), "r", encoding="latin-1") as infile:
            text = infile.read()

        if all(term in text for term in search_terms):
            print("{} in {} directory".format(f, dir_name))
```

Comment: it seems that this script shows only the first one file consisting the information from each folder and not all of them

Comment: @HalfPintBoy Is it possible that only first file fits the condition?

Comment: so for example, I checked it when put all the files in one folder with same search term it gives me 10 matches, when I do it in two different folders (same files) the result is only one match from each folder.